# Joomla: "Menu location" field missing from Add/Edit menu item dialog

Tags: joomla

There was a hardware problem with my hosting server. After the recovery all seems to work as it should but I can't add/edit menu items.

The system issues a:

Warning
Field required: Menu Location

and the menu item is not saved.

And indeed, I use the ISIS template for administration and on the right column the first field is Parent item when it supposed to be Menu location.

I uninstalled the Isis template and I uploaded and discover/install a new one from a fresh package but this didn't fix the issue.

Any ideea?

Thank you!

[On the right column the first field is "Parent item" when it supposed to be "Menu location"](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eqlbgv7eznxpw17/Screenshot%202014-12-12%2020.43.37.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

This wont be the template, but instead the menus component.

from a fresh package, copy and upload the contents of administrator/components/com_menus to the live site.

Comment: I did that now but it doesn't work. Could it be in the database?

Comment: If I set the error reporting to debug mode I get this:
Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, '', to be a valid callback in /home/user/public_html/libraries/joomla/filter/input.php on line 706

Comment: And if I change the administrative template to Hathor the Menu Location field shows and I can save the menu item.

There are some variations of Isis on the web (ex. Isis3). Those are not working either.